# client side certificate authentication code working in java7 and not in java8

Tags: java, java-8, ssl-certificate, rsa, client-certificates

I have written below code to connect to server using client side certificate authentication.

```
public void login()
    {
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
        ks.load(null, null);
        String kalg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        System.out.println(kalg);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(kalg);
        kmf.init(ks, null);
        String talg = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        System.out.println(talg);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(talg);
        KeyStore ts;
        ts = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT", "SunMSCAPI");

        ts.load(null, null);
        tmf.init(ts);
        TrustManager tm[] = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tm, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL("https://xxxxxx/");
        HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
        InputStream is = httpsCon.getInputStream();
        httpsCon.getHeaderFields();
        String str =httpsCon.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        System.out.println(httpsCon.getResponseMessage());
        int c;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((c = is.read()) >= 0) {
        System.out.print((char)c);
        sb.append((char) c);
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

for testing purposed I have created self signed server and client certificates.

This code works only in java 7, in java 8 it throws exception:

> java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports
>   this key: sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey

Is it something to do with some features introduced in java 8?

Comment: Did you install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength?

Comment: no.. I will do some research in JCE..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void login()
{
try {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
    ks.load(null, null);
    String kalg = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    System.out.println(kalg);
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(kalg);
    kmf.init(ks, null);
    String talg = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    System.out.println(talg);
    final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new       X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                final String authType) {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain,
                final String authType) {
        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    } };


    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection
        .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    URL url = new URL("xxxxx");
    HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
    InputStream is = httpsCon.getInputStream();
    httpsCon.getHeaderFields();
    String str =httpsCon.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
    System.out.println(httpsCon.getResponseMessage());
    int c;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((c = is.read()) >= 0) {
    System.out.print((char)c);
    sb.append((char) c);
    }
    is.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Add explanation to your code. Why will this code work and what was the problem in OP's code?